# Is it possible to search for existing HyperLinks inside of PDF's for known link data?

Tags: power-automate, hyperlink, pdf

We have a ton of PDF's in a `SharePoint Library` which we may need to update links on, but only if the links are from another specific library inside a separate `SharePoint`.  In trying to use a query `API`, I can search PDF's just fine in `Power Automate`, but I'm not able to search for any known hyperlink data.

Is this possible?

**NOTE - I am NOT trying to find hyperlinks on the `SharePoint` that point to PDF's, I'm trying to find PDF's that contain specific hyperlinks, or hyperlinks that contain specific substrings.**